# Overflow property in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, overflow

```css
.course_strip{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    height: 44px;
    color:#F1F1F1;
    line-height: 44px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
}
.course_strip p{
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.course_strip p:hover{
    background-color: #000;
}
.course_strip p:active{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.course_strip .glyphicon{
    line-height: 44px;
    top: 0px;
}
.course_strip_left p{
    float: left;
}
.course_strip_right p{
    float: right;
}
.left_container{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.left_container h2{
    margin-top: -4px;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.left_container p{
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding-left: 1px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="course_strip">
        <div class="course_strip_left">
            <p class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></p>
            <p>HTML</p>
            <p>CSS</p>
            <p>JAVASCRIPT</p>
            <p>SQL</p>
        </div>
        <div class="course_strip_right">
            <p class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></p>
            <p class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></p>
            <p>EXAMPLES</p>
            <p>REFERENCES</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left_container">
        <h2>HTML5 Tutorial</h2>
        <p>HTML HOME</p>
        <p>HTML Introduction</p>
        <p>HTML Editors</p>
        <p>HTML Basic</p>
        <p>HTML Elements</p>
        <p>HTML Attributes</p>
        <p>HTML Headings</p>
        <p>HTML Paragraphs</p>
        <p>HTML Styles</p>
        <p>HTML Formatting</p>
        <p>HTML Quotations</p>
        <p>HTML Comments</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right_container">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Till here, everything is fine for me,

But if I add, `overflow-y: scroll` to `.left_container` class in the CSS, then the left container shifts down a bit, introducing a strip of white background, which is not desired. I am unable to find out why adding overflow property to left_container shifting it down. Can someone please tell me why is it so? How can I resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: The code you provided does not make your example verifiable. Please create a working snippet inside the question, (using the `<>`  button), put each type of code in its dedicated panel and add all the necessary external libraries until the behavior you describe can be experienced here and inspected.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I have added the complete code now.

Comment: That's not what I suggested. I suggested you to created a **working** example. A [mcve]. Press the `<>` button when editing your question and you will understand what you need to do. We need to be able to inspect the example and see what properties apply to the element and why it has the extra space. It could be from `padding`, `margin`, from extra space between `inline-block`s. It could be caused by a lot of properties or combinations of properties. Without the ability to inspect it, we could only guess. And guessing is discouraged on [so].

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Added that. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, in your specific example, adding any `overflow-y` value other than `inerhit` makes `.left_container` detach from the margin, but I do know it has to do with block-level and visual formatting model.
Applying overflow to it makes it behave like `float:left` would. If I ever come across anything that would explain this behavior, I'll get back here and update.

---

As far as solutions go, the easiest way to achieve what you want would be to wrap your `.left_container` and `.right_container` in a custom wrapper (I named it `.layout-wrapper` below) and add this to your existing CSS:

```css
.layout-wrapper {
  padding-left: 20%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 44px);
}
.layout-wrapper .left_container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: calc(100% - 44px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Notes:

- you could obtain the same behavior with `position:fixed`.
- the same behavior can be achieved with `flexbox` and gives a large array of options for alignment and ordering. I opted for a "classic" block level solution since it has slightly better support and everything else in your example is using the same type of positioning.
- I changed `overflow-y:scroll` to `auto` but that's just a matter of preference. You can use `scroll` if you prefer to always see the bar.

Here it is, applied to your example:

```css
.course_strip{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    height: 44px;
    color:#F1F1F1;
    line-height: 44px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
}
.course_strip p{
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.course_strip p:hover{
    background-color: #000;
}
.course_strip p:active{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.course_strip .glyphicon{
    line-height: 44px;
    top: 0px;
}
.course_strip_left p{
    float: left;
}
.course_strip_right p{
    float: right;
}
.left_container{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.left_container h2{
    margin-top: -4px;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.left_container p{
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding-left: 1px;
    font-weight: 500;
}


.layout-wrapper {
  padding-left: 20%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 44px);
}
.layout-wrapper .left_container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: calc(100% - 44px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <div class="course_strip">
        <div class="course_strip_left">
            <p class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></p>
            <p>HTML</p>
            <p>CSS</p>
            <p>JAVASCRIPT</p>
            <p>SQL</p>
        </div>
        <div class="course_strip_right">
            <p class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></p>
            <p class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></p>
            <p>EXAMPLES</p>
            <p>REFERENCES</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="layout-wrapper">
      <div class="left_container">
        <h2>HTML5 Tutorial</h2>
        <p>HTML HOME</p>
        <p>HTML Introduction</p>
        <p>HTML Editors</p>
        <p>HTML Basic</p>
        <p>HTML Elements</p>
        <p>HTML Attributes</p>
        <p>HTML Headings</p>
        <p>HTML Paragraphs</p>
        <p>HTML Styles</p>
        <p>HTML Formatting</p>
        <p>HTML Quotations</p>
        <p>HTML Comments</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right_container">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Left container 
Float left display inline block
Height calc(100vh - top header height in px) 
Top header class must be given float left display inline block also 
The issue must be resolved

Answer (score -1):

you can add this code in your css

```
.course_strip{
float:left;
}
.left_container{
overflow:auto;
}
```